# Ubuntu 12.04 > Replace unity-settings-daemon with gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, keyboard, shortcuts

I would like to prevent unity-settings-daemon from starting up when I log in and instead have gnome-settings-daemon run. The reason is that the unity-settings-daemon is hilariously broken (namely custom keyboard shortcuts don't work), and I'm using GNOME Flashback instead of Unity anyways.

I know I can simply add a login task that runs 'gnome-settings-daemon --replace', but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution that avoids running unity-settings-daemon in the first place.

I deleted the launcher for unity-settings-daemon from /etc/xdg/autostart/ (interestingly, there was also a gnome-settings-daemon one in there), but it still starts up somehow.

P.S. I know there are hacks to get custom keyboard shortcuts to work with unity-settings-daemon; they actually seem to start working if you restart; I would rather eliminate unity-settings-daemon entirely

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and just uninstalled unity-settings-daemon. Might work for you, since you say that gnome-settings-daemon is already in your autostart.

Answer (score 0):

Since 13.10, the session manager (`gnome-session` by default) runs managed by yet another process manager: [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init).

With these kind of mixups, the graphical session startup process only gets more convoluted each release.  If you want to peek a bit, take a look in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions`.

In short, you have two possibilities:

1. Take a look at which session you are selecting, then go to `/usr/share/xsessions/YOUR_SESSION.desktop` and search for the text `X-LightDM-DesktopName`.  If its value is **different** than `GNOME`, choose another session type.
2. Create a file named `~/.xsessisonrc` and add the following line.

   export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME

Comment: Any idea why both gnome-settings-daemon and unity-settings-daemon would be both running at the same time by default? Seems crazy to me.